# How to retrieve data from firebase and save this data in textbox in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
func getInformation() {
     ref = Database.database().reference()

Handle = ref?.child("Users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let item = snapshot.value as? String {

    self.name.text = item
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand your question. So what you want to achieve here is, after a new user is added to the FirebaseDB, your textBox will want to show the name of the user added in real-time? In this case, if the user object added has a `name` field, the `snapshot.value` returned should be a `NSDictionary` instead of just a `String`. Try doing something like this instead:

```
if let newUser = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary,
   let newUserName = newUser["name"] as? String {
    self.name.text = newUserName
}
```